# Cross validation for multivariate imputation

Tags: r, cross-validation, data-imputation

I am currently using the mice: Multivariate Imputation by Chained Equations in R (JSS 2011 45(3)) package.

Consider the following example. I am using Sites B to Z and mice() to help infill missing data for Site A. The observations for Site A span the period 2002 to 2005 (there are some missing data in this period).

I have cross validated the infilled data over the period 2002 to 2005.

Because Sites B to Z cover the period 1995 to 2005, I would like to extend the record of Site A to also cover a similar period.

My question is: how I can check that the imputed values for Site A over the period 1995 to 2002 are reasonable? Obviously I cannot cross validate any data over this period.

Comment: Hi all. I can contribute to this based on my recent research. Apparently, a quick way to check the imputted values for Site A over the period 1995 to 2002 is to compare density plots of the imputted data to the observed data. I will continue to look for other checks.

Comment: You might get an answer if you described your data more clearly. Most importantly, start by describing your best guess for why data is missing for site A.  But also tell us how many observations do you have per site?  Are you representing different years on the same case as different observations/cases?  How many variables do you have, how many are missing, and what share of them are missing?